# Rename namespace only for one project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

i have a solution with 10 projects, but their namespaces are the same (WHY ;_;), i need to rename project per project, but with the rename tool rename the entire solution.

There is any way to rename the namespace of a specific project in Visual Studio?

sorry for the bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE** find and replace tool, you could mess up your solution.
One safe way to do it , `right click` on namespace, select `refactor` then hit `rename`, voila!

Answer (score 1):

Unload the projects you don't want to be affected. Refactoring tool will warn you next time you try, simply accept.